# Card Not Visible on Timeline

Tags: android, google-glass

I have Created a simple Card in Google Glass and set it like this

```
setContentView(card.toView());
```

When I install this app on my glass, it compiles itself for the first time, but I'm not able to see the card again if I swipe back to the timeline. I can do either :
-Re-install it again and again
-Run it through ADB by suppling package name.

> WHERE IS THE ALREADY INSTALLED CARD APP?

Comment: We need more information to help. Can you show us the code for your activity class and your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to create an [Immersion](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/immersions). In that case you need to define a voice trigger for it in your AndroidManifest as described here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#main_voice_commands

After doing this you will see your app in the "ok glass" menu.

Comment: Thanks Jacob It was a old question though I already did that voice thing and have some beautiful apps already ready ;)

Comment: I didn't realise the question was so old. Oh well, maybe someone else will find it useful.